# What does "associational meaning" mean?

Tags: terminology

I came across this term in a text on the linguistics of legislation: Frederick Bowers "Linguistic Aspects of Legislative Expression", chapter 2. I haven't found any definition or reference to it in other linguistic resources such as dictionaries or encyclopedias. Could someone enlighten me ?